# Error page styles not loading

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2

I was attempting to customize Magento's 503 and Maintenance error pages (404 is set up and works fine), but Magento can't load the stylesheets for the error pages.

If I put Magento in maintenance mode, or force some kind of DB error, it does load the appropriate page, but when it attempts to load `css/styles.css` that page, too, returns the error page instead if the css file.

How can I fix this?

Edit:

My folder structure, as requested

```
errors/
errors/404.php
errors/503.php
errors/design.xml
errors/local.xml
errors/processor.php
errors/report.php
errors/default/
errors/default/404.phtml
errors/default/503.phtml
errors/default/page.phtml
errors/default/report.phtml
errors/default/css/styles.css
errors/default/images/
```

I use `maintenance.flag` to force Magento to give me an error page. It tries to load `http://localhost/css/styles.css` but that returns a 503, so I get an unstyled error page.

If I access `http://localhost/errors/default/css/styles.css` I get the Magento error page, but it is styled (its able to load stylesheets). Loading any random url starting with the path `http://localhost/errors/default/` loads the error page correctly, so it seems to have something to do with how magento is building the error pages...

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure that you customized error pages in proper way.

Follow simple steps:

1. Go to `/errors and create new` folder for example `custom`.
2. Copy `/errors/default content` into /errors/custom.
3. Edit `/errors/design.xml` and set `custom` skin

   ```
   <config>
       <skin>default</skin>
   </config>
   ```

Now customize html files in `/errors/custom` end styles in `/errors/custom/styles.css`.

If you want to access your styles through browser `http://localhost/errors/custom/styles.css`

Also I recommend you to read [this article](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/customizing-the-magento-error-report-and-maintenance-page/).

Comment: even the default error pages do not render correctly

Comment: What is the problem with default pages?

Comment: Same problem- it can't load any external files. So references to the CSS and just return the error page.

Comment: Could you send me the url which you use to access css file?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: in regards to your edit, what I am trying to say is that even accessing `http://localhost/errors/custom/styles.css` or `http://localhost/errors/default/styles.css` does not load the css, it returns the error page (but without styles) and it will load the custom page if I set the xml to do so

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, accessing the css directly in the browser interestingly will render the error page with styles (instead of just printing out the css)

Comment: Could you add to the question the `error` folder structure. The header content of one of the html. Also check permissions to files inside `error` folder. Can your web server access them?

Comment: I've added more information

Comment: What is the content of `errors/design.xml` and `errors/local.xml`?