# Magento error pages don't load styles/images

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, error

I have Magento (1.9.2.1) installed in a subdirectory and turned "[maintenance mode on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201077/how-to-put-magento-in-maintenance)". Unfortunately, it doesn't load styles/images (e.g. "http://example.com/errors/default/images/logo.gif" is 404 Not Found) for error pages, in this case "Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable" page. Basically, an incorrect path produces 404 because it doesn't include a subdirectory. How can I fix this?

Related to: [Error page styles not loading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/error-page-styles-not-loading)

Comment: are you able to login to admin area?

Comment: Make sure that you have subdirectory in configuration for patch 'web/secure/base_url'  e.g. http://example.com/subdir/.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri, yes I am.

Comment: @kuba_ceg, I followed the [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749733/how-to-direct-magento-installation-path-in-subfolder-to-main-domain-name) and the rest works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `base` getting set correctly?  See this line in `errors/default/page.phtml`

```
<base href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl()?>" />
```

You may have to modify the/create a new template.

Answer (score 0):

Change in index.php file

`if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}`

when you enable maintenance mode it will redirect to 503.php change it as per your requirement

Change base URL in database core_config_data

Comment: I have changed it to:
`if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/subdirectory_name/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}`
Because I have Magento installed in a subdirectory.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: No. I had this in my code already.