# Magento 503 Error page no styles.css

Tags: magento-1.9, error, css, wamp

I am having an issue with the 503 page not using the styles.css file.
I am using Magento CE 1.9.3.0. I am hosting this website on my local machine using WAMP.
I have found this exact issue already asked [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/error-page-styles-not-loading).
But alas, this question leads to a dead end.

This is what I see:

[image: errorpage]

Instead of:

[image]

Either I am doing something wrong, or there's something different going on.
Also, my localhost uses port 8080 (because of WAMP and Skype having trouble with the port).
Any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is you’ve made some updates to Magento recently, and the maintenance.flag file in your Magento root directory wasn't successfully removed by the Magento Connect tool.

Comment: That´s not really the point. I need to have the maintenance.flag in the root directory as we want to customize our error page. I know that if you remove maintenance.flag, it will stop showing the error page.

Comment: Your problem is in the port 8080. Open file errors/processor.php (line 239) and replace the (80, 433) in the (8080, 433).

Comment: That's amazing, it works now! Thank you sooo much!